# Unable to use directory variable send to shell file to execute python script

Tags: python-3.x, shell

So I'm trying the send a variable which I created, to a shell script I am calling within the parent script. The variable happens to be contain a directory which contains my python.exe. I'm receiving the variable all right, but when i try appending /python and executing a python script I'm getting "ModuleImportError", but when i use the hard coded path every thing works fine.

## Parent script call startServiceConsumer

$PYTHON_HOME = /.conda/envs/mypika/bin

```
./startServiceConsumer.sh $PYTHON_HOME;
```

## startServiceConsumer.sh

```
pythonHome=$1
echo $pythonHome
cd src/Controllers # Source project

$pythonHome/python xyz.py
exit
```

## Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "xyz.py", line 3, in <module>
from src.Controllers import TaskProcessing
```